# Android Studio Blank Buttons

Tags: java, android, android-studio

so I am making a recipe app on android studio and I was using a different phone but then I switched phones to run the app and now my buttons are blank.Example:
[Old Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBBiC.png)

[New Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nsH3.png)

Any idea what could be causing this? this is for all my buttons.

Comment: It is likely that the button is not blank, the text color may have automatically changed to white depending on the theme of the device. Can you control the button text color by making it a specific color (red, blue, etc.)?

Comment: @OzgurBaykal oh thanks! man that solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of this problem is that the button text colour varies according to the device theme. If you make the button text colour a specific colour (red, blue etc.) you can see that it works properly on both devices.

*This answer was posted because the questioner confirmed in the comments that this was the source of the question.*